# Help with parametric equations and their inequalities

Tags: inequality, parametric

Could someone please help me with the inequality part of this question? I can eliminate the parameter but I don't understand how to find the inequality, or even how it's *relevant.*

x =2 cos $\theta$

y =$\sqrt3$ sin $\theta$

0 $\le$ $\theta$ $\le$ 2$\pi$

The equation I ended up with was:

$3x^2 + 4y^2 = 12 $

**Thanks**

Comment: Just for all $\theta\in(0,2\pi]$ you get all points  $(2\cos\theta,\sqrt3\sin\theta)$ on the ellipse $3x^2+4y^2=12$.

Comment: Thanks. The answers say -2 ≤ x ≤  2, how would I get to that?

Comment: Yes, of course, because $-1\leq\cos\theta\leq1.$

Comment: That's where I'm stumped. I don't understand how you get -1≤ cos θ
I thought cos(0)=1

Comment: By the definition of $\cos$ we have $-1\leq\cos\theta\leq1$ for all $\theta\in\mathbb R$.